# Final Builder action to change exe properties

Tags: finalbuilder

Is there a way to modify the properties of a file (exe in my case) with a final builder action after the file has been created?

Specifically, I'd like to change:

- File description
- Product name
- Product version

And remove:

- File version
- Original filename

[image: Properties Dialog]

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach with finalbuild is to set these values as part of the compile EXE action. For instance, when your FinalBuilder process includes a Compiler action you should be able to configure these values.

However if your doing this in a post exe built phase, Try the **Wind32 Version Info Updater Action**.